# Nuxt command line pass arguments

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I want to pass some arguments to `nuxt` command line like:

```
nuxt --myvar a
```

How to read this `myvar` inside `nuxt.config.js`?

I need this because I have 3 `.env` (localhost, production and development) files, but with current `NODE_ENV` I can use only 2 (production and development).

Comment: At the end I did it with `const hasMyVar = process.argv.includes("--myvar");` but is is just boolean and doesn't look nice as for me. Because instead of passing param I need to introduce few booleans and based on them to choose proper file.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out the https://github.com/nuxt-community/dotenv-module.

> The module loads variables from your .env file directly into your
>   nuxt.js application `context` and `process.env`.

Comment: Yes, I'm using this module, but to use certain `.env` file I have to do something like:
`require("dotenv").config({ path: envFilename })` but how I can differentiate `envFilename`? Based on what? I was using `NODE_ENV` but there are only 2 options, I need 3.

Comment: Aha I understand what is your problem now. What I have seen work in practice is to not have multiple .env files as part of your repository, but to have only one `.env` per environment and make it a part of the deployment process to inject the proper file (still the same name).